# Burn bootstrapper is not detecting Windows installer version correctly

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

Currently, I have the following fragment to check and install Windows Installer 4.5 if the user is on Windows XP.

```
<Fragment>
    <Property Id="WinXPx86HasInstaller">
      <![CDATA[VersionNT = 'v5.1' AND  VersionMsi >= "4.5.6001.22159"]]>
    </Property>

    <PackageGroup Id="Windows.Installer.4.5">
        <ExePackage Id="WinXp_x86"
                    Cache="no"
                    Compressed="no"
                    PerMachine="yes"
                    Permanent="yes"
                    Vital="yes"
                    InstallCommand="/norestart /passive"
                    SourceFile="WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe"
                    DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/6/1/261fca42-22c0-4f91-9451-0e0f2e08356d/WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe"
                    DetectCondition="WinXPx86HasInstaller"
                    InstallCondition="NOT WinXPx86HasInstaller">
            <ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot" />
        </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

However, this is not working and the property "WinXPx86HasInstaller" always evaluates to false even when it is installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's somewhat annoying that, unlike WiX, there's no way to easily test Burn InstallConditions - only DetectConditions are printed out in the log at runtime. After spending a while to test *inverted* InstallConditions as DetectConditions [*], this fragment appears to work for me:

```
<!-- Windows Installer 4.5 -->
<Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="WindowsInstaller45">
        <ExePackage
            Cache="no"
            Compressed="no"
            PerMachine="yes"
            Permanent="yes"
            Vital="yes"
            SourceFile="redist\WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe"
            DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/6/1/261fca42-22c0-4f91-9451-0e0f2e08356d/WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe"
            InstallCondition="VersionNT=v5.1 AND NOT VersionNT64 AND VersionMsi &lt; v4.5"
            InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart">
            <ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot"/>
        </ExePackage>
        <ExePackage
            Cache="no"
            Compressed="no"
            PerMachine="yes"
            Permanent="yes"
            Vital="yes"
            SourceFile="redist\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x86.exe"
            DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/6/1/261fca42-22c0-4f91-9451-0e0f2e08356d/WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x86.exe"
            InstallCondition="VersionNT=v5.2 AND NOT VersionNT64 AND VersionMsi &lt; v4.5"
            InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart">
            <ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot"/>
        </ExePackage>
        <ExePackage
            Cache="no"
            Compressed="no"
            PerMachine="yes"
            Permanent="yes"
            Vital="yes"
            SourceFile="redist\WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe"
            DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/6/1/261fca42-22c0-4f91-9451-0e0f2e08356d/WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe"
            InstallCondition="VersionNT=v5.2 AND VersionNT64 AND VersionMsi &lt; v4.5"
            InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart">
            <ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot"/>
        </ExePackage>
        <MsuPackage
            Cache="no"
            Compressed="no"
            Permanent="yes"
            Vital="yes"
            KB="KB942288"
            SourceFile="redist\Windows6.0-KB942288-v2-x86.msu"
            DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/6/1/261fca42-22c0-4f91-9451-0e0f2e08356d/Windows6.0-KB942288-v2-x86.msu"
            InstallCondition="VersionNT=v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64 AND VersionMsi &lt; v4.5"/>
        <MsuPackage
            Cache="no"
            Compressed="no"
            Permanent="yes"
            Vital="yes"
            KB="KB942288"
            SourceFile="redist\Windows6.0-KB942288-v2-x64.msu"
            DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/6/1/261fca42-22c0-4f91-9451-0e0f2e08356d/Windows6.0-KB942288-v2-x64.msu"
            InstallCondition="VersionNT=v6.0 AND VersionNT64 AND VersionMsi &lt; v4.5"/>
    </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Awesome that's works perfectly. Thanks a lot. Thanks for the other platforms too, I hadn't got round to doing those yet! ;)

Comment: I think the install condition should be changed to "(VersionNT=v5.2 OR VersionNT=v5.1) AND VersionNT64 AND VersionMsi &lt; v4.5" on the Server 2003 x64 ExePackage.

From [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8483), For Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2 and Windows XP 64-bit Editions:
x64 Platform: WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe.

Comment: @jchoover There was only ever a 32-bit version of NT 5.1: 64-bit XP and 2003 were 5.2 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx .

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, I believe the original reason as to why your detection was failing would be because VersionMsi only has two digits of precision:

```
<![CDATA[VersionNT = 'v5.1' AND  VersionMsi >= "4.5.6001.22159"]]>
```

should have been

```
<![CDATA[VersionNT = 'v5.1' AND  VersionMsi >= v4.5]]>
```

I had recently struggled with a similar issue and ended up digging into [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) to find the answer.

```
static HRESULT InitializeVariableVersionMsi(
__in DWORD_PTR dwpData,
__inout BURN_VARIANT* pValue
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dwpData);

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    DLLGETVERSIONPROC pfnMsiDllGetVersion = NULL;
    DLLVERSIONINFO msiVersionInfo = { };

    // Get DllGetVersion proc address
    pfnMsiDllGetVersion = (DLLGETVERSIONPROC)::GetProcAddress(::GetModuleHandleW(L"msi"), "DllGetVersion");
    ExitOnNullWithLastError(pfnMsiDllGetVersion, hr, "Failed to find DllGetVersion entry point in msi.dll.");

    // Get msi.dll version information
    msiVersionInfo.cbSize = sizeof(DLLVERSIONINFO);
    hr = pfnMsiDllGetVersion(&msiVersionInfo);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to get msi.dll version info.");

    hr = BVariantSetVersion(pValue, MAKEQWORDVERSION(msiVersionInfo.dwMajorVersion, msiVersionInfo.dwMinorVersion, 0, 0));
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to set variant value.");

    LExit:
    return hr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
DetectCondition="VersionMsi >= v4.5 AND VersionNT = 501 AND NOT VersionNT64"
```

And I think, `InstallCondition` is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Version NT has values 501, 502, 600, etc. The value is an integer: MajorVersion * 100 + MinorVersion. Use '501' instead of 'v5.1'.

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Not according to the Burn documentation, http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/bundle_built_in_variables.htm. I have checked the burn sourcecode and as far as I can see the docs above are correct (C++ is very rusty). I actually had 501 in my original code before I noticed the discrepancy and it didn't work then either.

Comment: VersionNT is both a Burn variable and an MSI property. In this case, I think it will be treated as an MSI property.

Comment: Why do you think that? The code above is within the Burn bootstrapper not an msi. In any case I've tried both and neither work. :(

Comment: I haven't worked much with CDATA conditions (they seem just weird to me :-/ ), but I think the condition here should be: <![CDATA[VersionNT <> 501 OR  VersionMsi < "4.5.6001.22159"]]>.

Comment: A cleaner approach here would be using the condition directly in DetectCondition as in: DetectCondition="VersionNT=501 AND VersionMsi &gt;= "4.5.6001.22159"". Also, DetectCondition alone is sufficient for determining if the package will be installed. You don't need the InstallCondition attribute.

Comment: You were indeed correct, @caveman_dick, it's supposed to be in v#.# format. Looks like Burn uses a different parser for version strings rather than Windows Installer.